# iis 6.2 using aspnet_compiler.exe to Precompile

Tags: iis-6, aspnet-compiler

I am using IIS 6.2 and able to pre-complie in place an application successfully using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe using the parameters -p "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" -v "/VirtualApplication"

it create the cache fold as expected, the issue is when I access the site from a browser iis does not use the existing cache folder it is making a new folder. 
How do I Instruct IIS to use the precompiled version. on IIS 6.2 what is the best practice for Precompiling in place.

Answer (score 0):

[Precompile ASP.NET Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms227972(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

The `-p` parameter is the path to your actual website which will be something like C:\InetPub\MySite

The `-v` parameter is the path the web browser will use which will be just a forward-slash if it is the root. IE:/ If your site is to be reached at stackoverflow.com then your virtualPath would be / but if your site was at stackoverflow.com/MySite then your virtualPath would be /mySite

aspnet_compiler will create compiled copies of your website's .NET libraries and save them somewhere on the system that you don't need to worry about because IIS will automatically use them instead of compiling new ones.